# Removing / Overlaying logo on mp4 video format with ffmpeg on linux

Tags: video, video-editor, ffmpeg, mp4, filter

I'm trying to remove a logo from an .MP4 video format with ffmpeg on a Linux machine without re-encoding (for preserving the same quality) with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf delogo=x=270:y=190:w=40:h=40 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

and it gives me the following errors:

```
Unrecognized option 'vf'
```

then a new error came up:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'delogo=x=270:y=190:w=40:h=40'
```

ffmpeg is always updating and it seems that they change command line arguments a lot so any material or tutorial I find online seems to get outdated quickly.

I review their website documentation but can't get it to work, I think i'm missing something...?

What is the correct command line in Linux shell;
also, how to view or find out exactly the area coordinates to be removed before actually removing logo/overlaying it and keep testing every while?
And how to overlay a solid color in certain area instead of removing logo transparently as well?

Comment: It is discouraged to crosspost the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108229/removing-overlaying-logo-on-mp4-video-format-with-ffmpeg-on-linux) on multiple Stack Exchange sites (and it is offtopic on Stack Overflow; that site is for programming questions only).

Comment: Understood Sir, Pardon me for writing the same question on the other site as well, but i figured out the other is having much more traffic volume than this, also found 8K ffmpeg specific questions there as well, I might vote for deleting this one.

Answer (score 6):

Your command is missing double quotes around the filter definition :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=270:y=190:w=40:h=40" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

(as explained in [FFmpeg filters documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Description))

Nevertheless, this filter will decode and re-encode your video stream.